# Generate a multi-indexed dataframe from a dictionary with different length of values

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dictionary:

```
dic = {'T1':["2013-11-12 17:35:00", "2013-11-12 17:36:00", "2013-11-12 17:37:00", "2013-11-12 17:38:00", 
               "2013-11-12 17:40:00", "2013-11-12 17:41:00", "2013-11-12 17:42:00"], 'T2':["2013-11-12 12:15:00", "2013-11-12 12:16:00", "2013-11-13 16:32:00", "2013-11-13 16:33:00", 
               "2013-11-13 16:34:00"]}
```

From which I would like to generate the following `multiIndexed` dataframe:

```
                      T1                                            T2
         Start                   Stop                   Start                Stop
   2013-11-12 17:35:00  2013-11-12 17:38:00     2013-11-12 12:15:00  2013-11-12 12:16:00
   2013-11-12 17:40:00  2013-11-12 17:42:00     2013-11-13 16:32:00  2013-11-13 16:34:00
```

What the dataframe describes is the time that some incident started and ended for either sensors T1 or T2. If the time difference between two incidences is less than 1 minute I assume it is the same incident continuing whereas when this difference is greater than 1 minute it indicates start of a new incident.

I appreciate any help :)

Comment: What should be the result if `dic = { 'T1': ["2013-11-12 17:38:00", "2013-11-12 17:40:00", "2013-11-12 17:42:00"] }`?

Comment: @unutbu we will have 3 incidents in total so it should be:  Start : 2013-11-12 17:38:00----Stop : 2013-11-12 17:38:00, Start : 2013-11-12 17:40:00----Stop : 2013-11-12 17:40:00, Start:2013-11-12 17:42:00 ----Stop : 2013-11-12 17:42:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could compute the difference between consecutive Timestamps, and form a mask which is True when the difference is not 1 minute:

```
df['mask'] = (df[key].diff() / np.timedelta64(1, 'm')) != 1
```

Then take the cumsum of the mask to identify which rows belong to which group:

```
df['group'] = df['mask'].cumsum()
```

yields something like:

```
                   T2   mask  group
0 2013-11-12 12:15:00   True      1
1 2013-11-12 12:16:00  False      1
2 2013-11-13 16:32:00   True      2
3 2013-11-13 16:33:00  False      2
4 2013-11-13 16:34:00  False      2

                   T1  mask  group
0 2013-11-12 17:38:00  True      1
1 2013-11-12 17:40:00  True      2
2 2013-11-12 17:42:00  True      3
```

Now groupby the `group` column and for each group find the first and last Timestamp:

```
result[key] = df.groupby(['group'])[key].agg(['first', 'last'])
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
pd.options.display.width = 1000
dic = {'T1':["2013-11-12 17:35:00", "2013-11-12 17:36:00", "2013-11-12 17:37:00", 
             "2013-11-12 17:38:00", "2013-11-12 17:40:00", "2013-11-12 17:41:00", 
             "2013-11-12 17:42:00"], 
       'T2':["2013-11-12 12:15:00", "2013-11-12 12:16:00", "2013-11-13 16:32:00", 
             "2013-11-13 16:33:00", "2013-11-13 16:34:00"]}

result = dict()
for key, val in dic.items():
    df = pd.DataFrame({key: pd.to_datetime(val)})
    df['mask'] = (df[key].diff() / np.timedelta64(1, 'm')) != 1
    df['group'] = df['mask'].cumsum()
    result[key] = df.groupby(['group'])[key].agg(['first', 'last'])
    result[key] = result[key].rename(columns={'first':'Start', 'last':'Stop'})
result = pd.concat(result, axis=1)
print(result)
```

yields

```
                       T1                                      T2                    
                    Start                Stop               Start                Stop
group                                                                                
1     2013-11-12 17:35:00 2013-11-12 17:38:00 2013-11-12 12:15:00 2013-11-12 12:16:00
2     2013-11-12 17:40:00 2013-11-12 17:42:00 2013-11-13 16:32:00 2013-11-13 16:34:00
```